# struts2 form submit via javascript with hidden parameters

Tags: javascript, struts2

Below is code snippet from JSP

```
<s:form action="SubmitLogon" onfocus="username">
<s:hidden name="lastsession" value="N"/>
<s:hidden name="duplicateurl" />

<table>
<tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <button type="Submit" value="Login" style="WIDTH: 98px; HEIGHT: 39px; background:Transparent; border:None" onclick="submitLogon()">
                    <img src='/images/btn_login.jpg' />
                    </button>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
</table>
</s:form>
```

Below is my javasacript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2">
function submitLogon(){
    //alert('urlUnEncoded-----------'+document.URLUnencoded);
    document.LogonForm.duplicateurl.value = document.URLUnencoded;
    //alert('duplicateurl-----------'+document.LogonForm.duplicateurl.value);
    var dupURL = document.LogonForm.duplicateurl.value;
    alert("dupURL------------"+dupURL);
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

when i click on submit, form is getting submitted to StrutsAction(SubmitLogon) but hidden paramter (i.e duplicateurl is  getting as empty, **not even null**)

duplicateurl is defined in Action class with all its setters and getters, i'm sure there is no issue in Action class

*moreover below code which exists in javascript function is not popped with alert but form submitted successfully*

```
alert("dupURL------------"+dupURL);
```

Any solution provided will be helpful to me

Comment: Look at the rendered form--what's the name of the form? What's the result in the console of typing `document.LoginForm`?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, yes it was creating problem